# linq to object query to exclude 0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq, c#-4.0

I have a Linq query as below.

```
var DataSource = from m in product
                 select new { Class = m.Class, Id = (new Make(m.Id)).ProductName};
```

I instantiate a class called `Make` and fetch the `ProductName` based on the `Id`.
Some of the Id's are 0.
Is there a way I can exclude all the Id's that are 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `where` clause:

```
where m.Id != 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just do this:

```
var DataSource = from m in product
                 where m.Id != 0
                 select new
                 {
                     Class = m.Class,
                     Id = (new Make(m.Id)).ProductName
                 };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var DataSource = from m in product
                 where m.Id != 0
                 select new
                 {
                     Class = m.Class,
                     Id = (new Make(m.Id)).ProductName
                 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var DataSource = from m in product
                               where m.Id != 0
                               select new { Class = m.Class, Id = (new Make(m.Id)).ProductName};
```